# Probability Problem based on the a set of numbers. Determine if the number is divisible by three

Tags: probability

Three distinct numbers are selected at random from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. What is the probability that their product is divisible by $3$?

I think that since because $3$ and $6$ are the only numbers that divide into three with an integer remainder, the number would have to have $3$ or $6$ in the unit's digit. Since this is the case the probability would be  $2/6$ or $1/3$. Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: You are correct that to be a product of 3, one of the terms must be 3 or 6.  What I don't understand is how you got that the probability of that is 2/6.  Work on that.

Comment: There are ${6\choose 3} $ ways to pick 3 elements.  ${4\choose 3} $ of those have neither 3 nor 6.  So ${6\choose 3}-{4\choose 6} $ have a 3 or a 6 or both.  So probability is $\frac {{6\choose 3}-{4-3}}{6\choose 3}$

Answer (score 2):

We need to find the probability that **at least** one of the numbers is divisible by three. This is the same as

$$\begin{align*}
1-P(\text{none of the numbers are divisible by three})
&=1-\left(\frac{4}{6}\cdot\frac{3}{5}\cdot\frac{2}{4}\right)\\\\
&=1-0.2\\\\
&=0.8
\end{align*}$$

In order to get three numbers that are not $3$ or $6$, we must first select $1,2,4,$ or $5$ out of the six numbers giving a probability of $\frac{4}{6}$.

Take that number away. We must now select one of the remaining three numbers of the five with probability $\frac{3}{5}$.

Finally, we must now select one of the two remaining numbers of the four with probability $\frac{2}{4}$

Comment: Where did you get 4/6, 3/5 and 2/4. It would be better if you explain your solution?

Comment: Does that explanation help?